# Establishing DGPS Connection With Old Equipment?

Tags: gps, land-survey

I am trying to do a differential surveying project with some outdated equipment, specifically:

-An old AllegroCX personal handheld computer (Win 4.1) with SurvCE loaded on it to collect data and establish communication

-Two Novatel ProPak V3 Recievers (one for base, one for rover)

-Two external radio communicators

-Two pinwheel style antennas

I am able to establish a connection with the rover's Novatel reviever and AllegroCX using a serial cable, but I cannot get it to find the base receiver using radio communications. Is this possible wirelessly, or do I need to set up the base station via serial cable as well? Do I need to have a PC connected to the base receiver?

Answer (score 1):

Both the base and rover need to be configured with SurvCE in order to properly define the settings of each (base coordinates, elevation mask, message type, etc.). Also, the radios must have settings configured so they are properly communicating (frequency, modulation type, etc.). Do note, that if you are in the US and these are not narrow band radios (12.5kHz), I believe it is now illegal to operate at 1 watt or over.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I figured as much. Do you know if it's a requirement to write a script to place into the base reciever's memory, or if SurvCE is capable of doing this?

Comment: If SurvCE has the drivers for your GNSS receivers, then it can be utilized to configure each instrument. If the drivers are not present, you may have to use another configuration method, like running a script file.